# Can I use two mysql users on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I use one database which contains two MySQL users, and now I want to know if it is possible to use two MySQL users in one database in codeigniter..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! 
Use 2 Database connections to SAME DB with different username / password !

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: Any explanation/reference?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a second set of database parameters. CI isn’t developed to really have two DB connections though, it is more for swapping test and production dbases. That said there are some tricks around it. So first define a second set of DB info like so:

```
/* FORUM */
$active_group = "forum";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['forum']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['forum']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['forum']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['forum']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['forum']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['forum']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

/* TEST SITE */
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Your active db will be the one you defined LAST.

Once you have done this you can manually connect to the second one (or put it in MY_Controller if you always need to). You can then load your second database like so:

```
$this->other_db= $this->CI->load->database('forum', TRUE);
```

Access dbase 1 with `$this->db` and dbase 2 with `$this->other_db` (or whatever you called it).

thank you

That should do it. The documentation for connecting to multiple databases can be found here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/database/connecting.html